# Nested ssh connection

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to connect via ssh to the server and from this server connect to another server via ssh. Do you know if there are any extensions that would allow me to do so?

Comment: Similarly, I'm trying to ssh to a first machine via the "remote SSH" extension and then I want to SSH to GitHub from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use

```
ssh -t userid1@machine1 "ssh userid2@machine2"
```

assuming that you have a ssh client on the first target?

Comment: yeah I know that, but there are many extensions that loads files to the workspace from server that you are connected to using ssh, that would only connect me in the terminal