# Connecting to Nested SSH on VSCode using RSA key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am trying to connect to an ssh server on VSCode. I have done it using Remote Control before which was not an issue. Now I need to connect nested ssh which I couldn't figure out how to.

I have tried other answers on this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41493/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-using-another-server and [Nested ssh connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710249/nested-ssh-connection) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/ssh-via-multiple-hosts. But nothing seems to work for my case.

The machine I am using belongs to a lab so I do not have full auth. I use rsa keys to enter each one. And I tried using;
`ssh -i id_rsa user@ip "ssh -it second_rsa user2@new_ip"` and it didn't seem to work (it works for terminal but not vscode)

Is there anyway I can use `-i` and still be able to access the second ssh using only one command (and on vscode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, a little tweaking on the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b

My local config file looks like this:

```sh
Host name_of_host
  HostName ip_1
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' ubuntu@ip_2 'ssh-add ~/id_rsa_2 && nc %h %p'
```